# Perl: Replace all , found between two characters in perl

Tags: perl

I am new to perl.

I have an input string like
Dave,30,"6,000","4,500","60,000","1,000"

I need to replace all the quotes and also all the commas found between the quotes

my expected output:
Dave,30,6000,4500,60000,1000

Comment: Can you show what you've tried, so we can help you out?  In general, this being CSV data, you'd want to use a library to parse that data, like [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV), and then you can output it any way you want.  Btw: your "_expected output_" doesn't show that you "_replace_" commas?

Comment: Sorry for my incorrect explanation. I wanted all those commas to be replaced(removed) which comes within the quotes. "6,000" becomes 6000 and so on.

Comment: Step 1: Parse as CSV. Step 2: Remove commas from each value in each row. The reason I say CSV parse is because you may have quotes within quotes as the [CSV format](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) is quite...unusual.

Comment: Thanks for the your idea. But out of curosity may i ask, if we have a way to first identify the substring within quotes (using regex or so) and then replace all commas in that sub string and then put it back to the original position. That should work right?
Step 1: identify 6,000 from the main string (similarly for other cases)
Step 2: Remove, from 6,000 and make it 6000
Step 3: Replace "6,000" in the main string using 6000 that we got in step 2

But the only problem would then be how can i identify the substring for step 1

Comment: Getting the "_substring for step 1_" is the "parsing" part, best done by a library

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest using something like Text::CSV to parse comma separated values. There are a lot of subtle ways that CSV files can be a pain in the neck.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl


use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

if ($csv->parse(q{Dave,30,"6,000","4,500","60,000","1,000"})) {
    # strip extraneous commas
    my @fields = map { (my $s = $_) =~ s/,//; $s } $csv->fields;

    # print out the results
    $csv->combine(@fields);
    say $csv->string;
}
```

This prints the line `Dave,30,6000,4500,60000,1000`

Comment: `map { s/,//gr }` would be enough (`g` to remove all the commas and `r` to return the modified string).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution I came up with. Not the most elegant, but it will do

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    
    my $s="Dave,30,\"6,000\",\"4,500\",\"60,000\",\"1,000\"";
    my $q=0;
    my $r = "";
    my @a = unpack "(a1)*",$s;
    
    foreach (@a)
       { 
       if ($_ eq '"')
          {
          $q=1-$q; 
          next;
          }
       next
          if $_ eq "," && $q; 
       $r.=$_;
       }
    
    printf "%s\n",$r;
```